# Get element on touchstart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, touch-event

I have a series of divs on a page which you can swipe left on, which will reveal a div underneath. This works fine when there is only one element, but when there are multiple, they all swipe in unison, instead of the one getting swiped alone.

To remedy this, I tried the ideas here: [Find element finger is on during a touchend event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523496/find-element-finger-is-on-during-a-touchend-event)

Problem is, now only the first element gets swiped, while the rest of them stay stationary. Any ideas on how I could fix this? I thought I could use `this`, but it would always return the `window` object.

Code:

```
var originalCoord = {
        x: 100,
        y: 100
    }
    var finalCoord = {
        x: 100,
        y: 100
    }

    function touchMove(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        finalCoord.x = event.targetTouches[0].pageX
        finalCoord.y = event.targetTouches[0].pageY
    }

    function touchEnd(event) {
        var changeY = originalCoord.y - finalCoord.y
        if (changeY < 30 && changeY > (30 * -1)) {
            changeX = originalCoord.x - finalCoord.x
            if (changeX > 10) {
               var elem = document.elementFromPoint(event.pageX, event.pageY);
               console.log(elem);
                $(elem).css("margin-left", "-54px");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(elem).css("margin-left", "0px");}
                , 500);
            }
        }
    }

    function touchStart(event) {
        originalCoord.x = event.targetTouches[0].pageX
        originalCoord.y = event.targetTouches[0].pageY
        finalCoord.x = originalCoord.x
        finalCoord.y = originalCoord.y
    }

    this.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStart, false);
    this.addEventListener("touchmove", touchMove, false);
    this.addEventListener("touchend", touchEnd, false);
```

Demo (only works on iOS): http://www.codekraken.com/testing/snowday/swipe.html

Comment: I didn't think anything was that simple... could you post that as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the element which the event originated in by using `event.target`.

```
function touchStart(event){
  var currentElement = event.target;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id').on('touchstart',function(e,data) {             
    var obj = e.target;
    obj = $(this);
    var id = obj.find....   
});
```

with `obj = $(this)` you can transform `event.target` into a jquery-object using jquery functions...

best

M

Comment: It is a best pratice to use [ $obj = $(this) ] use $ to indicate it is a jQuery object