# How to get target element on touch end event handler?

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, touch

I have function touchstart, touchmove & touchend handler like bellow for an container, the container contains number of elements. In the touchmove handler I am drawing line in canvas.

```
function touchStartHandler(e){
   var elem = e.target;
   console.log($(elem).text());
}
function touchEndHandler(e){
   var elem = e.target;
   console.log($(elem).text());
}
function touchMoveHandler(e){
   //
}
```

I want to get the element in the touchend. **The event's target is the same element that received the touchstart event**. Any solution for this to get element in the touchend event?

Comment: *"The event's target is the same element that received the touchstart event."* Shouldn't it be? What element are you expecting?

Comment: What about creating global variables? Then the assignation on the first `touchstart` will be in the scope of the `touchend`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for your reply, In container I have number of DIV elements as grid. on touch start i can get the target in the event (div element 1). I am release touch in the div element 5. On the touchend event handler I am getting element 1 as target. But I need to receive element 5.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `e.changedTouches.item(0)`

```
function touchEndHandler(e){
   var elem = e.changedTouches.item(0) ;
   console.log($(elem).text());
}
```

Take a look at this question for more info:
[Find element finger is on during a touchend event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523496/find-element-finger-is-on-during-a-touchend-event)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.